# .style("background-position", function(){...}) not populating the attribute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Full code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rczun/5/

The important part is at the end where I wish to use my sample data set to the correct "background-position" for the element according to the data set, the log displays that there is iteration and the data is good but it's still not being assigned.

```
var container = d3.select('.icon-selection-container').attr('width',500);

var s = container.selectAll('.icon')
.data(icon_defs);

s.enter()
.append('div')
.attr({
    class : 'icon icon-book'
})
.style("background-image", "url('http://static.mabelslabels.com/images/booklabels2.png')")
.style("background-position", function(d,i) {
        var bgPos = d.style.slice(20);//clean sample data up
        console.log(bgPos);
        return bgPos;
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the ; at the end of the value, so it work with

```
var bgPos = d.style.slice(21,-1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rczun/6/